# Searching for a Data Dictionary for SQL or Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, metadata

I am looking for metadata specifications (data dictionary) for SQL Server and Oracle databases.

By metadata map, I mean a definitive description of what objects make up database model and their relationships (i.e. a server has 0:n databases, a table has 1:n columns, a column has 0:n constraints).

Any versions of these DBMS platforms would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

I've Community Wiki'd this

Oracle

- Storage can hold multiple databases
- Databases can be opened by multiple instances
- Server can run run multiple instances
- A server can only run a single instace for any given database
- Data is stored in tablespaces
- A tablespace may be made up of multiple data files
- Tables/indexes/Materialized Views can be partitioned across multiple segments
- A segment lives on a tablespace
- A database object (table, index, stored program unit...) is owned by a user
- A table may be be referenced (through a foreign key constraint) by another table, including a table owned by another user
- A table may have at most one primary key constraint
- A table may have zero or more unique constraints
- A primary key or unique constraint is logically enforced by exactly one index (though you could have a multi-column unique constraint which is backed up by multiple unique indexes with the columns in a differing order)
- An index may be unique or non-unique. A unique constraint may be enforced by a unique or non-unique index.
- A table must have at least one column
- Each column has a datatype (and optionally a length or precision/scale)
- A trigger may relate to at most a single table. (Some triggers, such as SERVERERROR, don't relate to a table).

Comment: Thanks, why the cw? It wasn't a definitive answer, however it was certainly useful and deserving a +1

Comment: Databases can only be opened by multiple instances in RAC...

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, the [Sybase poster](http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/asg1250e/poster.pdf) will largely apply. The [Oracle Interactive Quick Reference](http://landingpad.oracle.com/webapps/dialogue/ns/dlgwelcome.jsp?p_ext=Y&p_dlg_id=9575302&src=7027600&Act=54) may also help.

Comment: Cheers, both very useful

Comment: I have a real poster of the Sybase one, 15 years old now :-)